# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED Trying to send RASA responses to slack channel

Tags: python, slack, rasa

I'm connecting my RASA chatbot to a Slack channel interface. When I send a message, Rasa interprets it correctly, however, it is not able to send the response to the Slack channel.

Rasa server shows this exception:

```
 Task exception was never retrieved future: <Task finished name='Task-11' coro=<register.<locals>.handler() done, defined at C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa\core\channels\channel.py:88> exception=ClientConnectorCertificateError(ConnectionKey(host='www.slack.com', port=443, is_ssl=True, ssl=None, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None, proxy_headers_hash=None), SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)'))>
```

I know Rasa handles the messages correctly because in the Rasa action server, the code shows running.

any help, please?